# JS Function Return True if all Variables in it Return True

Tags: javascript

the function below validates my form, where each variable calls a function to make sure the field has been filled out.  If the field is not filled out, the function returns FALSE and thus the variable is FALSE.  I am wondering how I can make this function return TRUE if all the variables return TRUE.

Right now it returns FALSE every time because of that last line.  Thanks!

```
function validateform(){
        var namevalid = validatename();
        var entreevalid = validateentree();
        var fillingvalid = validatefilling();
        var ricevalid = validaterice();
        var beansvalid = validatebeans();
        var cheesevalid = validatecheese();

        return false;

}
```

Comment: Seriously? You should be able to figure this out, even if you did it the verbose way using separate `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of local variable at all:

```
function validateform() {
    return validatename() && validateentree() &&
           validatefilling() && validaterice() &&
           validatebeans() && validatecheese();
}
```

The benefit is that subsequent functions will not be called if previous returns false, so the whole code is a little bit more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateform(){
        var namevalid    = validatename(),
            entreevalid  = validateentree(),
            fillingvalid = validatefilling(),
            ricevalid    = validaterice(),
            beansvalid   = validatebeans(),
            cheesevalid  = validatecheese();

        return (namevalid && entreevalid && fillingvalid && 
                ricevalid && beansvalid  && cheesevalid);
}
```

Comment: I'm giving you +1 for the alignment... sweet, sweet alignment.

Comment: @amnotiam - Thanks, me like order!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Change this:

```
return false;
```

To this:

```
return (namevalid && entreevalid && fillingvalid && ricevalid && beansvalid && cheesevalid);
```

Answer (score 0):

A less messy version than creating variables for each check:

```
function validateform(){
        return (validatename() && validateentree() && validatefilling() 
               && validaterice() && validatebeans() && validatecheese());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short version:

```
return (validatename() && validateentree() && validatefilling() && 
        validaterice() && validatebeans() && validatecheese());
```